# Should a method in a class be aware that the class has "loaded" a variable?

Tags: object-oriented, code-quality

So I have the following code, which connects and then binds to an LDAP server.

The question is in the first method.

```
  public function getUsers() // This is the method in question
  {
    if( $this->connect()->bind() ) {
      ldap_query(self::$connection) // Here, should it be aware that class succesfully loaded
         // the connection, or should the bind() method return the resource?
    }
  }

  public function connect()
  {
    self::$connection = ldap_connect($this->host);
    if( ! self::$connection ) {
      throw new \CHttpException(503, 'No se puede establecer una conexión con el servidor '.$this->host);
    }
    foreach( $this->options as $option => $value ) {
      ldap_set_option(self::$connection, constant($option), $value);
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function bind()
  {
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind(self::$connection, $this->username.'@'.$this->domain, $this->password);
    if( ! $ldapbind ) {
      throw new \CHttpException(503, 'No se puede enlazar con el servidor: '.ldap_error(self::$connection));
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes (or objects as instances of classes) create a local scope where member variables serve as "global" within the boundaries of this scope. This is intentional, so it is perfectly ok if one member function initializes a member variable and a second makes use of the fact the first function finished successfully without an exception.

So in your case: if `bind()` initializes  `$ldapbind` (and does not throw an exception), there is no reason to return `$ldapbind`. `getUsers` can just safely assume `$ldapbind` to be initialized.

Comment: Interestingly I was trying to further understand it and came to this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196929/can-should-the-single-responsibility-principle-be-applied-to-new-code that was answered by you. I found it clear and useful, mostly the last part where you talk about the task of the method (in the EDIT). Thanks for taking the time to answer those things and help others.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having to worry about your class successfully creating and binding a connection.  Have the resource passed in to class as part of the constructor.  The connect and bind would be part of their own class that would return the resource that you pass in to the class that calls `getUsers`.  Then you don't have to worry whether or not a connection was actually made to use as it has to exist for to even use the class.

You could alternatively have a `Connection` interface that your class expects which wraps the resource and provides a `query` method that you would use to get the users in your `getUsers` method.  This way if you decide to change what you connect to get your users, you only need to create a new class that uses the `Connection` interface and it will work without any problem.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion since it makes the create/bind connection more resuable, and the class in stake becomes more unit-testable. However, assumed I understood the question correctly, I think this post does not answer it.

Comment: By moving the success of the other methods outside of the class, we then no longer have to worry about their success.  The OP was asking what if anything should be returned by the other methods, my answer being that the methods shouldn't exist.  But I do see what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Since this is a "component level" class in Yii Framework I'm not allowed to pass things in constructor. (Like I would with Symfony2, I think -still learning-), so I have to do it inside the class. The suggestion is good, thought I find separation of classes an obscure place, because we always have something to move to another class.